# Change user URL

Tags: users, urls

When user created URL comes as **www.sitename.com/user/username**

I want to change to
**www.sitename.com/username** (Remove User from URL)

How can I do this

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Permalinks and set it up as follows

> Custom Structure 
>   and put . in category base

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by Category base?, I have a blog so can't use Category.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add_rewrite_rule`, which matches a regular expression in the url with a query on index.php.

In your functions.php or plugin:

```
function yourdomain_user_rewrite_rule() {

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^([^/]*)/?$',                              // matches anything
        'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]',        // to ?author_name
        'top'                                       // run before other queries
    );

    // this cleans the rewrite rules and make it work
    // its very slow! Remove from production!
    flush_rewrite_rules();                    
}

add_action( 'init', 'yourdomain_user_rewrite_rule' );
```

Rembemer to remove `flush_rewrite_rules` from produciton. You can bind it to a plugin activate hook, or simply to go settings > permalinks and save ( which does flushes rules for you ).

**BUT!** You'll run into a problem, which is: you have lost the query that finds your pages!

There are two ways you could go about fixing this:

1. Hook into `pre_get_post` do do user checks and modify the query OR
2. Add a new rule for pages.

I'd advise the second, since if you are doing checks on pre_get_post you are adding extra calls to your database, which will make things slow.

So, to add a new query, its easy:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
   '^page/([^/]*)/?$',
   'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]',
   'top'
);
```

Add that to `yourdomain_user_rewrite_rule` to route all pages to yourdomain/page/pagename.

Hope that helps!